# How to use a private method in Java

Tags: java, methods, private-methods

I am given a class that has a private method say setCoors(int x, int y). The constructor of that class has the setCoors in it too. In a different class, I want to have a method setLocation which calls setCoors. Is this possible?

New Question:

If I am not allowed to set the method to public, is this possible?

```
public class Coordinate{
    public Coordinate(int a, int b){
        setCoors(a,b)
    }
    private void setCoords(int x, int y)
}

public class Location{
    private Coordinate  loc;
    public void setLocation(int a, int b)
        loc = new Coordinate(a,b)
}
```

Comment: @RayToal - you're making some big assumptions. Given that he doesn't understand the whole public vs. private thing, I doubt his class has quite made it to reflection yet. Of course, that's an assumption too ... just a slightly smaller one given that he's stating the constructor calls the private method ...  ;)

Comment: @Brian I do agree that yes, the answer of "no" is more helpful because you're right the question _is_ coming from a beginning Java context.  I'm not opposed to leaving the answer in place for other visitors to the page, but if there is consensus that it does not belong I can withdraw it.  Still, I can't decide, though, whether the _best_ answer is a qualified no; something like "well no you can't but weeeeellllll, there _is_ this really complicated back door that lets you do it but no one does this except these evil hackers and you can learn about it later...."  Or maybe not. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `private` means the method can only be called inside of the Class in which it is defined.  You will probably want to have `setLocation` create a new instance of the class `setCoords` resides in, or change the visibility on `setCoords`.

**EDIT:** The code you have posted will work.  Just be aware that any instance of the `Location` class will be bound to its own `Coordinate` object.  If you create a new `Coordinate` object somewhere else in your code, you will be unable to modify its internal state.  In other words, the line

```
Coordinate myCoord = new Coordinate(4, 5);
```

will create the object `myCoord` which will forever have the coordinates `4` and `5`.

Comment: So if I'm not allowed to make setCoords public. then in setLocation, do I do something like this: setLocation(int a, int b) { coords = new Coordinate(a,b)? assuming setCoords in is Coordinate class

Comment: Yes, assuming that is what you want.  Without seeing the class design, it's hard to tell if that is the right way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 7):

The best and most helpful answer depends on the context of the question, which is, I believe, not completely obvious.

If the question was a novice question about the *intended* meaning of private, then the answer "no" is completely appropriate.  That is:

- private members of A are accessible only within class A
- package-private members of A are accessible only within classes in A's package
- protected members of A are accessible only within classes in A's package and subclasses of A
- public members of A are accessible anywhere A is visible.

Now, *if*, and okay maybe this is a stretch (thank you Brian :) ), that the question came from a more "advanced" context where one is looking at the question of "I know private means private but is there a language loophole", then, well, there **is** such a loophole.  It goes like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class C {
    private int x = 10;
    private void hello() {System.out.println("Well hello there");}
}

public class PrivateAccessDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        C c = new C();
        List<Field> fields = Arrays.asList(C.class.getDeclaredFields());
        for (Field f: fields) {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            System.out.println(f.getName() + " = " + f.get(c));
        }
        List<Method> methods = Arrays.asList(C.class.getDeclaredMethods());
        for (Method m: methods) {
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
x = 10
Well hello there
```

Of course, this really isn't something that application programmers would ever do.  But the fact that such a thing *can be done* is worthwhile to know, and not something that should be ignored.  IMHO anyway.

Comment: Seriously, you're going to "help" a student that doesn't understand public vs. private with reflection?

Comment: haha too funny.  Ray is right, but I think Brian is even more right. ;)  "No" is a much better answer.  :)

Comment: Actually there is no way to tell from the question that the student does not understand public versus private.  This could have been a research question in an advanced class.  But your question is fair.  I will qualify the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`private` means it's **private**

If you want other classes to call it, maybe you shouldn't make it private?

Comment: As @Dan said in his reply to my answer, he can't change the visibility of the `setCoords` method.

Comment: Not true. It can be accessed with reflection. He didn't ask if he should, he asked if he could. Now I fully agree that you should tell him he shouldn't, but that doesn't change the fact that the correct answer is "Yes, but ..."

Answer (score 3):

No `private` methods can't be accessed outside the class in which they are defined

Answer (score 3):

Kid-doing-homework: the answer is no.  Guy-requiring-some-crazy-work-around-for-his-job: the answer is yes.  Far more importantly though, Your `setCoors` method should not take int arguments.  It should take two `SilverBullet` objects.

Answer (score 1):

`private` means you can only access it inside the class defined.